# Refactor function that reading files from folders tree

Tags: go

I have the following structure of my project like that:

- main.go
- /data
- - /1
- - - 1.json
- - /2
- - - 2.json
- - /3
- - - 3.json

And I have the following function that works well

```
const (
    data          = "./data"
)

type Hello struct {
    S string `json:"hello"`
}

func myFunc() {
    folders, err := os.ReadDir(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("read dir: %s", err)
    }

    for _, folder := range folders {
        path := filepath.Join(data, folder.Name())
        files, err := os.ReadDir(path)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("read dir: %s", err)
        }
        for _, file := range files {
            pathToFile := filepath.Join(path, file.Name())
            b, err := os.ReadFile(pathToFile)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }

            h := Hello{}

            err = json.Unmarshal(b, &h)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("unmarshall erro: %w\n", err)
            }

            fmt.Println(h)
        }
    }
}
```

I should refactor my data tree and divide data folder into two additional folders. So my structure should be like this:

- main.go
- /data
- - /dog
- - - /1
- - - - 1.json
- - - /2
- - - - 2.json
- - /cat
- - - /3
- - - - 3.json

So I need to fix my function according to this structure of the files.
I don't want to hardcode and make the solution with additional `for` loop. But I think it is not good solution.

```
func myfunc() {
    subFolders, err := os.ReadDir(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("read dir: %s", err)
    }

    for _, subFolder := range subFolders {

        pathToSubFolder := filepath.Join(data, subFolder.Name())

        folders, err := os.ReadDir(pathToSubFolder)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("read dir1: %s", err)
        }

        for _, folder := range folders {
            path := filepath.Join(pathToSubFolder, folder.Name())

            files, err := os.ReadDir(path)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("read dir2: %s", err)
            }
            for _, file := range files {
                pathToFile := filepath.Join(path, file.Name())
                b, err := os.ReadFile(pathToFile)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println(err)
                }

                h := Hello{}

                err = json.Unmarshal(b, &h)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("unmarshall erro: %w\n", err)
                }

                fmt.Println(h)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This soultion works but can anyone suggest another solution that could be better?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't the right site for a code review, but you can try your luck on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps in the #reviews channel on https://gophers.slack.com.

Comment: Maybe you need some recursive logic here, try to search for solutions that way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. the code in the project is more complex, here just want to show the main idea.